# How to build a Eclipse RCP with Maven and Tycho

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rcp, tycho

I've got the following situation:
A eclipse rcp project which requires another bundle (with some jars in it) to run. This runs very fine when I start it from eclipse.
Now I want to create a runnable jar **with maven and tycho** (this is very important).

The pom.xml in the eclipse rcp project looks like this

```
<properties>
        <tycho-version>0.16.0</tycho-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>helios</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>galileoTest</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6-JUnit-Tests/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The build process is 'succesful', but the resulting jar is olny 74kb (must be over 15mb) and is not executable (no main class found).

Comment: I think your pom.xml is not sufficient to successfully build a rcp-product. You can read [Eclipse Tycho - Tutorial for building Eclipse Plugins and RCP applications](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html) from Lars Vogel to get a very good overview how to build rcp applications with `tycho`.

Comment: Look here for an example for building an eclipse rcp project with maven and tycho: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html

Comment: I don't think that Eclipse RCP applications can be packed as a single runnable JAR. The common distribution format is an archive with multiple files, like what is available for download at eclipse.org.

Comment: Did you ever come around to fixing this? What was the solution?